# React Native Navigation Open Draw From Header Button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to open a navigation draw from a stack navigation header button. The header button is showing up fine but when I click the button I am getting

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigate')

I can't seem to find a solid example of how to do this or if its even possible with react navigation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { Draw } from './DrawNav.js'

export const RootStack = createStackNavigator (
  {
    DrawNav: {
      screen: Draw,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        //Hide the shadow of the header
        headerStyle: {
          elevation:0,
          shadowColor: 'transparent',
          shadowRadius: 0,
          shadowOffset: {
            height: 0,
          }
        },
        headerLeft: (
          <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
            <Icon
              name="menu"
              size={25}
              color="#D4AF37"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
          </View>
        ),
      })
    },
  },
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.props` is only used in a react class. I assume you're using react-navigation v2 then you should dispatch DrawerAction like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { Draw } from './DrawNav.js'

  export const RootStack = createStackNavigator (
  {
    DrawNav: {
      screen: Draw,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        //Hide the shadow of the header
        headerStyle: {
          elevation:0,
          shadowColor: 'transparent',
          shadowRadius: 0,
          shadowOffset: {
            height: 0,
          }
        },
        headerLeft: (
          <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
            <Icon
              name="menu"
              size={25}
              color="#D4AF37"
              onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
            />
          </View>
        ),
      })
    },
  },
);
```